# How can I ensure enough space is left to avoid content moving down the page if a warning message appears?

Tags: html, css, django

I have a server-side rendered application (Django) with a login page which provides a username and password field, submit button, instructions for forgotten password and so on. This is what I will call the "main content".

Sometimes, there will an extra div above the main content with a message such as "Invalid username or password". I would like it so that if the user submits an invalid login and this message appears, the main content doesn't move. (I'm aware that this will involve leaving a white space above the main content, but there's a lot of blank space on this page anyway so it doesn't matter)

I considered rendering

```
<div class="warning-message">Invalid username or password</div>
```

if required and some kind of placeholder

```
<div class="placeholder"></div>
```

otherwise, but I was struggling to style them so that the empty div would always be the same height as the warning message one.

I did also consider positioning either the main content or the warning message with `position:absolute`, but this sometimes leads to overlapping on small screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I'd forgotten that when an element is hidden in CSS with the `visibility` property, it still takes up space on the page - which is exactly what I wanted.

So

```
   <div class="warning-message"

   {% if form.errors %}
   style="visibility: visible"
   {% else %}
   style="visibility: hidden"

   {% endif %}>
```

did the trick nicely.